# gnuplot - 2d interpolation, don't explicitly list x-values

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to generate using GNUPlot, a 2d plot from a list of y-axis values, without stating explicitly the corresponding x-value. In other words, I do not have

```
  x  y
  1  5
  2  3
  3  5
  4  6
  5  14
```

but instead have

```
5 10 3 5 6 14 (y-values listed only, not x values)
```

How can I generate a 2d plot from this, by specifying only the bounds of x, assuming uniforming spacing, and not explicitly listing x?

Then I would like to interpolate the y-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `0` pseudocolumn for this:

> ```
>    column(0)   The sequential order of each point within a data set.
>                The counter starts at 0 and is reset by two sequential blank
>                records.  The shorthand form $0 is available.
> ```

In order to start counting from 1, the example below uses `($0+1)`. If needed, a more general form would be `$0*step + xMin`, where `xMin` denotes the required minimum value of `x` and `step` stands for the step size (spacing of individual x values).

```
unset key

$data <<EOD
5
10
3
5
6
14
EOD

fit (a*x + b) $data u ($0+1):1 via a,b

plot \
    $data u ($0+1):1 w lp, \
    a*x + b w l lc rgb 'red' lw 2
```